# some EOF mechanism for send(),recv() in C

Tags: c, sockets

I wonder, If i do 4 send() with my client, written in C, will my server need to read() 4 times, or could it be that the first read will read all 4 send()'s all together?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, that your server receives all four sends in one go. After all, it's just a byte stream. Nothing more, nothing less. The only way to prevent that from happening is adhering to a protocol, where you only receive one 'packet' at a time. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: could you guide me a little more? I wish to send a file, in a format where i first send an integer (=file name size), then its name, followed by file's size (bytes) and then the data itself. im having difficulties with the first part

Answer (score 4):

To help you out a little, you've basically answered your own question already.

You need to do it 'in tiers', so to speak.

Client:

```
int len = strlen(Filename) + 1; //Mind the terminating 0.
send(sock, (const char *)&len, sizeof(int), 0);
send(sock, Filename, len, 0);  //Sending the filename
send(sock, &FileSize, sizeof(int), 0);
send(sock, FileBuf, FileSize, 0);
```

This code will send the entire data on the way (assuming that the entire file is in the 'FileBuf'-Variable).

Server:

```
int len;
char *FileBuf, FileName[20];
recv(sock, &len, sizeof(int), 0);  //Receives the filename length. (4 Bytes)
recv(sock, FileName, len, 0);      //Receives the filename (x bytes)
recv(sock, &len, sizeof(int), 0);  //Receives the file length (again, 4 bytes)
FileBuf = new char[len];           //Creates sufficient space in memory.
recv(sock, FileBuf, len, 0);       //Receives the file into the appropriate variable.
```

This is the absolute barebones variant, not very solid, but you should get the idea.

A more robust approach requires you to check the return values of recv() and send(). Both will return the amount of bytes, which have been processed with this call. If this amount equals '0', it means that the connection has been closed by the other end. (Mainly for `recv()`). If it equals -1, it means that something went wrong and you should check the `errno` variable.

If all goes well, it equals the exact amount of bytes you sent/tried to receive.

However in case it isn't 'len' (or 0 or -1), you could write a little wrapper like this.

```
unsigned char Recv(int sock, void *target, int Len) {
    unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)target, Ret = 0;
    int RecvBytes = 1;
    while(Len && !Ret) {
        RecvBytes = recv(sock, ptr, Len, 0);
        if(!RecvBytes) Ret = 1;
        else if(RecvBytes == -1) Ret = errno;
        else {
            Len -= RecvBytes;
            ptr += RecvBytes;
        }
    }
    return Ret;
}
```

What this code does: It keeps receiving, until you either have received all the data you were expecting (the `Len` parameter) or an error occurred. If all goes well, it returns '0', which you can check with `if(!Recv())`.

Another useful wrapper function (a shortcut, so to speak) is this one:

```
uint32_t RecvInt(int sock) {
    uint32_t Ret;
    Recv(sock, &Ret, sizeof(Ret));
    return ntohl(Ret);
}
```

This function receives exactly one unsigned int and corrects the endianess from network byte order to host byte order. (Network byte order is always big endian, host byte order is often: Little endian)

Using these wrapper functions, the code may be changed like this:

```
uint32_t len;
char *FileBuf, FileName[20];
len = RecvInt(sock);               //Receives the filename length. (4 Bytes)
Recv(sock, FileName, len);         //Receives the filename (x bytes)
len = RecvInt(sock);               //Receives the file length (again, 4 bytes)
FileBuf = new char[len];           //Creates sufficient space in memory.
Recv(sock, FileBuf, len);          //Receives the file into the appropriate variable.
```

Comment: You should use a type with a well-defined size, such as `uint32_t` instead of `int`, because the size of `int` on the sender and the size of `int` on the receiver might not be the same. You should also use `ntohl()` and `htonl()` on the sends and receives of the integers because the byte order of the sender and receiver might not be the same.

Comment: @Celada Yes, you are of course right, that Endianess and the width of the datatypes are of the utmost importance. Let me add it.

Comment: @e-r-a-n Redesign it? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

**For stream sockets (e.g. TCP)**: it makes no difference how many `send()` or `write()` calls were made on the sending end. The data could be returned in as few as one chunk, as many as n chunks of 1 byte each (where n is the number of bytes that were sent), or anything in between.

**For datagram sockets (e.g. UDP)**: each `recv()` or `recvmsg()` call will return one complete datagram that was sent from the other end. The number of `recv()` or `recvmsg()` calls should be the same as the number of datagrams that were sent. `recv()` is preferred when reading from datagram sockets, but I believe `read()` should behave the same.

Comment: Isn't it `recvfrom` for UDP?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium `recvfrom()` is just the same as `recv()` with a few extra arguments. It can be used anytime `recv()` can be used. It is in fact useful with TCP if you need to use a flag such as `MSG_OOB` (which will return TCP urgent data).

Answer (score 0):

The number of `write()`s and `read()` need not be the same - it's possible that the `write()` writes all the data in one piece but on the other computer `read()` only manages to receive it in several chunks, and vice versa. That's why you should **always check the return value** of these functions and if only partial data transfer occurred, then continue with sending/receiving the rest.

Comment: I do check, of course, that each send() did send everything, but Im having troubles seperating it back on the server side, where i read() it. beacuse of the fact that it may be reading once, all 4 send()'s

Comment: @e-r-a-n "all 4 send()s" - all 4 sends what?

Comment: I meant that my issue is basically because (As i suspected, because its TCP) that all 4 sends() at the client side can be read at once (eg 1 recv) at the server side. that is my main issue, where I dont know how to deal with. can I just attach some delimeter, non-ascii? the problem is I dont know what delim i can use, as in linux systems all ascii codes are acceptable as file name

Comment: @e-r-a-n Why would you ever need the number of `write()`s on the other end? I suspect your code needs to be redesigned if you rely on this. Use a data format that makes sense and write code that generates and parses it.